# Postgres column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function error.

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
portal=# \d+ accounts_version
                                      Table "public.accounts_version"
          Column          |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                       | integer                     | not null  | plain    |              | 
 status                   | account_status              |           | plain    |              | 
 adwords_id               | character varying(20)       |           | extended |              | 
 nickname                 | character varying(48)       |           | extended |              | 
 account_budget           | double precision            |           | plain    |              | 
 remaining_account_budget | double precision            |           | plain    |              | 
 daily_budget             | double precision            |           | plain    |              | 
 currency                 | character varying(12)       |           | extended |              | 
 exchange_rate            | double precision            |           | plain    |              | 
 login                    | character varying(48)       |           | extended |              | 
 password                 | character varying(48)       |           | extended |              | 
 billing                  | character varying(48)       |           | extended |              | 
 auto_tag_on              | boolean                     |           | plain    |              | 
 mcc_id                   | integer                     |           | plain    |              | 
 vps_id                   | integer                     |           | plain    |              | 
 client_id                | integer                     |           | plain    |              | 
 transaction_id           | bigint                      | not null  | plain    |              | 
 end_transaction_id       | bigint                      |           | plain    |              | 
 operation_type           | smallint                    | not null  | plain    |              | 
 country                  | character varying(24)       |           | extended |              | 
 external_comment         | text                        |           | extended |              | 
 internal_comment         | text                        |           | extended |              | 
 batch                    | character varying(48)       |           | extended |              | 
 updated_at               | timestamp without time zone |           | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "accounts_version_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, transaction_id)
    "ix_accounts_version_end_transaction_id" btree (end_transaction_id)
    "ix_accounts_version_operation_type" btree (operation_type)
    "ix_accounts_version_transaction_id" btree (transaction_id)
```

I am trying to query for the latest entry into this table for each adwords_id.

So I am started writing my sql query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts_version GROUP BY adwords_id;
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "accounts_version.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM accounts_version

           ^
```

I am running postgres 9.5. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM accounts_version GROUP BY adwords_id;` is not a valid query as the error is correctly suggesting. for a group by query, some fields can be grouped upon. all other fields must be aggregate expressions.

Answer (score 0):

[PostgreSQL GROUP BY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) takes the group by column expression as an input which will raise error when the column is of type text and its not used in an aggregate function Refer to [SELECT - GROUP BY- Transact-SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` is not the correct way to do this. What you want is `DISTINCT ON`. To get the row with the latest `updated_at` for each `adwords_id`, try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (adwords_id) *
FROM accounts_version
ORDER BY updated_at DESCENDING;
```